# Passing in and setting global int through main

Tags: c, variables, global, program-entry-point

I've been trying to create a tester for my Stack ADT, by dynamically passing in the amount of items to add to the stack. However, when I try passing in an integer, for instance, 22, it assigns the global variable (ITEMS) as 50. If I try something else, the range is between 45, and 55.

My main function is this:

```
int main(int numArgs, char* numItems[]) {
    Stack stack;

    if (numArgs == 0) {
        printf("Good job, you broke C.\n");
    } else if (numArgs == 2) {
        int items = (int)*numItems[1];
        if(*numItems[1] != ITEMS) {
            setItems(items);
        } 
    } else if (numArgs>=3) {
        printf("Usage: TestStack <numItems> <-help>\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if(numItems[1] == "-h" || numItems[2] == "-help") {
        printf("numItems   - Number of items to add to the stack.\n            -h     (-help) -  Shows this help output.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* test code here*/
}
```

The assignment function is:

```
static void setItems(int numItems) {
    ITEMS = numItems;
    printf("ITEMS IS %d\n",ITEMS);
}
```

And my global variable is just

```
int ITEMS = 11; //Default value.
```

Any reason that I can't actually get the real value I'm trying to pass in?

Comment: the arguments come in a strings, so you are getting the value of the first character in the string. As Chris notes below, you need to convert the string to an integer.

Comment: `printf("Good job, you broke C.\n");` - Now this is hilarious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
int items = (int)*numItems[1];
```

This will read the `int` value of the first `char` that you pass in... Since you pass in `22`, it will get the ASCII Valule of `2` which is 50.  [Refer to this chart](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) (thanks asciitable.com) under **Dec 50**:

[image: ASCII table]

What you want to do instead is interpret the whole cstring as an integer, using `atoi`:

```
int items = atoi(numItems[1]);
```

or `strtol`:

```
int items = strtol(numItems[1], NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to C, so atoi is completely new to me. Thanks though, it worked!

Comment: "It will get the ASCII Valule of 2" - even if your system is non-ASCII? Don't mislead beginners. The C standard says nothing about the character encoding used.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something like `numItems = atoi(argv[1])` instead of casting the first character of said argument to an `int`. Read up in the manual page on `atoi(3)`. And do yourself a favor, go read Steve Summit's [C tutorial](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html) (yes, it is dated, but still very relevant). Also read Rob Pike's ramblings on [C style](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/pikestyle.html).

Answer (score 0):

In `C` program command line arguments will be received as strings even you pass integers or float.

If you pass 10, then `argv[1]` will have the address of string of two bytes which has ASCII value of `1`(49) and `0`(48). So `*argv[1]` will give the value of first byte, which is 49. If you try to print that as character you will get `1` or you will get `48` if you try to print it as integer.

```
printf("%s", argv[1]) //will print 10
printf("%u", argv[1]) //will print address of the string "10"
printf("%c", *argv[1]) //will print 1
printf("%d", *argv[1]) //will print 49
```

Answer (score 0):

So others basically made the point: the value you're obtaining is not `22` but the character code of the first character of `"22"`, which is the character code of `2` (probably 50, if your system uses ASCII or Unicode).

But for the love of God, don't use `atoi()`! It's deprecated, ugly, unsafe and incomplete. You should be using `strtol()` or `strtoll()` instead:

```
int theNum = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
```